# Assign Matrix field entry in Playa

Tags: matrix, playa

I've been using Matrix for quite a long time and yesterday I bought Playa because I thought that it can do what I need.

I have a channel "Movies" and a channel "People". I made a Matrix field for the People channel with the column "Names" because some people have alias names. I made a a Matrix field for "Movies" with the columns "Name" and "Role". Name is a Playa field and I thought it's possible to make a setting that I can chose that I can select from the "People" matrix name Field.

So what I need in publish for the movies is a field where I can select a
person (entry) from the people channel and then one of this persons alias.

John Doe (this is a entry)
- David (this is a alias)
- Steven (this is a alias)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Playa can only create relationships between entries, not individual fields. If you have the development skills, this would be a good candidate for a custom fieldtype if it doesn't already exist. (You could use [moreMatrixRelations](https://github.com/moresoda/ft.matrix_relations.ee_addon) as a starting point for your own matrix-compatible field).

Alternatively, you could store all the alias names as entries (either in the People channel or in a new channel) and then use Playa to relate the aliases to the people and a pair of Playa fields nested in Matrix columns to choose both the person and his alias in the Movies entries. This could get quite unwieldy however, and performance would probably become an issue if a Matrix grows much beyond a dozen rows.